# erasing a layer where mouse is over it

Tags: actionscript-3

I got the following question.

i added the following elements to the stage:

```
homeBg = new HomeBg();
homeMask = new HomeDrawBg();
addChild(homeBg);
addChild(homeMask);
```

I allready instantiated them in the beginning of the document. But my problem is the following. the homeBg layer is a image, the homeMask layer is the same image but it has a pencil scetch look. What i want is that wherever i move my mouse, the homemask layer should be erased so the bottom layer becomes visible(only where the mask is erased). So how can i tell the mask layer to erase itself if the mouse is over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer attempt 2**

You can use the blendMode property of a display object to achieve this.  Here's the code (tested):

```
// set the eraser width (diameter)
var eraserWidth:int = 20;

//get the HomeMask library item
var homeMask:HomeMask = new HomeDrawBg();
homeMask.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
addChild(homeMask);

// create the eraser shape
var eraser:Shape = new Shape();
eraser.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
eraser.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,eraserWidth/2);
eraser.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
homeMask.addChild(eraser);

homeMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseOverMask);

function mouseOverMask(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    eraser.x = homeMask.mouseX;
    eraser.y = homeMask.mouseY;
}
```

There are a couple of important bits here.

Firstly, you must set the blendMode of the thing you want to erase to `BlendMode.LAYER`.

Secondly (and this is what has tricked me before) your eraser,  with `BlendMode.ERASE`, must be a child of the object you're wanting to erase.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, or i jus didnt explain it correctly, i just want to erase the part of the mask where my mouse is over, so not the entire mask. say where ever my mouse is i generate a elipse of a 10px radius. the elipse is linked to my mouse position, so where my elipse is, thats where the mask should be erased, only the size of the elipse. So only the the original image is shown and it should create the effect that the skecth image is being coulored where my mouse is

Comment: Ah, ok.  That's a little more complicated.  I'll have to build a test before amending my answer, unless someone else gets there first!

Comment: More accurate answer, tested and with explanation.

Comment: After testing it, it looks very nice, only one more thing that didnt work, when i go over the image it gets erased nicely but it goes back to the scetch image when the mouse leaves the point that was erased.

Comment: OK, that's a different thing again.  What you need to make the erase stay (like a paint brush, but erasing) is to create a bitmap layer instide your homeMask that you will draw onto.  That will be your erase layer, and the mouse will paint onto it. Give it a try and put up another question if you get stuck.

Comment: You cant believe how gratefull i am, after adding some blur and tweens the final result is here: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1310983006  ty again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:http://www.piterwilson.com/personal/2008/05/07/bitmapdata-erasing-in-as3-with-custom-brush-shape/

Comment: This is using BlendMode.INVERT to affect the base bitmap, but will not work with erase because `pointer_mc` is not a child of the target (and can never be because the target is a bitmap).

Comment: This is what i'm looking for yes, one more question, tyvm, one more question thou, instead of adding the elipse to the stage, is it possible to tween it from small to big? so it acts more like a inkdrop with a blurred border? Sorry for the annoying questions but i'm not to familiar with bitmapdata yet.

Comment: Sorry, not understand your question.